# Merging feature class with same name from several geodatabases into single geodatabase using Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, merge

I have 10 geodatabases, each one has 20 feature class on average, and every one feature class has the same name. What I want is a merge from every single feature class with the same name into another geodatabase.

I made a script where first all list all the feature class from the geodatabase, but I am stuck I don't know how to realize the merge from every several geodatabases into one geodatabase.

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C\...\GDBESTATALES_PRUEBA' #This is my folder where I have all my geodatabases

OutputMerge = r'C\...\Resultado\GDB_Nacional\GDB_Nacional.gdb'#This is the gdb where I want to save all the merges

List_workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()
List_featureclass = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for ws in List_workspaces:
    print ws
    env.workspace = ws
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in fcs:
        print fc
    #I don't know what to do after this point
```

How do I merge the feature class from several geodatabases into another geodatabase?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create the output Feature Class and you can do it using an existing Feature Class as template:

> out_fc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path = 'output_ws_path', out_name = 'fcs_merge', template = fc)

Then you can use Append to load all the features from each fc within the for loop:

> arcpy.Append_management(fc, out_fc, 'NO_TEST')